# Extracting values from existing dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I need to gather information from an existing dataset.
The dataset looks as follows:

```
Source      Target     Label_S  Weight   Prop_1    Prop_2  Mer_1   Mer_2
car         airplane     0.5       0.2     1         0      0       0
car         train        0.5       0.5     1         1      0       1
car         bike         0.5       0.2     1         1      0       0
bike        motorbike    1       0.7       1         1      0       1
bike        car          1       0.2       1         1      0       0
airplane    car          -1      0.2       0         1      0       0         
train       car          1       0.5       1         1      1       0  
motorbike   car          1       0.7       1         1      1       0
motorbike   toy          1       0.6       1         0      1       1
```

`Label_S, Prop_1` and `Mer_1` are `Source`'s properties; `Prop_2` and `Mer_2` are `Target`'s properties.
I am trying to create a list of unique nodes from both `Source` and `Target`, including their properties; something like this:

```
Node       Label_S  Property   Merchandising
car        0.5        1             0
airplane   -1         0             0
train      1          1             1
bike       1          1             0 
motorbike  1          1             1
toy                   0             1
```

I had not problem to create the list including all the nodes:

```
source = df['Source'].unique().tolist()
target = df['Target'].unique().tolist()
all_nodes=list(source + target)
```

but I am not actually understanding how to get information from properties columns based on `Source`/`Target` information.

I think I should first split the dataframe in two dataframes: one with `Source` plus the properties of `Source`; the other one with `Target` elements plus the properties of Target.
Once got this information, maybe it could be good to append the two dataframes and remove duplicates under the column `Node`. But I feel that something is wrong: for example, I have `Label_S` which is a property of `Source` and not of Target...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but you can first create two distinct dataframes for source and target and aggregate the properties in lists:

```
df_s = df[["Source", "Label_S", "Prop_1", "Mer_1"]].groupby("Source").agg(list)
df_t = df[["Target", "Weight", "Prop_2", "Mer_2"]].groupby("Target").agg(list)

print(df_s)
print(df_t)
```

Output:

```
                   Label_S     Prop_1      Mer_1
Source                                          
airplane            [-1.0]        [0]        [0]
bike            [1.0, 1.0]     [1, 1]     [0, 0]
car        [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]  [1, 1, 1]  [0, 0, 0]
motorbike       [1.0, 1.0]     [1, 1]     [1, 1]
train                [1.0]        [1]        [1]
                         Weight        Prop_2         Mer_2
Target                                                     
airplane                  [0.2]           [0]           [0]
bike                      [0.2]           [1]           [0]
car        [0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7]  [1, 1, 1, 1]  [0, 0, 0, 0]
motorbike                 [0.7]           [1]           [1]
toy                       [0.6]           [0]           [1]
train                     [0.5]           [1]           [1]
```

###### Edit

You can aggregate the properties differently to keep only one value (e.g. `max`), then merge you dataframes:

```
df_s = df[["Source", "Label_S", "Prop_1", "Mer_1"]].groupby("Source", as_index=False).agg(max)
df_t = df[["Target", "Weight", "Prop_2", "Mer_2"]].groupby("Target", as_index=False).agg(max)

df_s.columns = ["Node", "Label_S", "Property", "Merchandising"]
df_t.columns = ["Node", "Weight", "Property", "Merchandising"]

print(df_s.merge(df_t, how="outer").set_index("Node"))
```

Output:

```
           Label_S  Property  Merchandising  Weight
Node                                               
airplane      -1.0         0              0     0.2
bike           1.0         1              0     0.2
car            0.5         1              0     0.7
motorbike      1.0         1              1     0.7
train          1.0         1              1     0.5
toy            NaN         0              1     0.6
```

If you want to exclude the `Weight` column:

```
print(df_s.merge(df_t[["Node", "Property", "Merchandising"]], how="outer").set_index("Node"))
```

Comment: Hi Tranbi, Thank you for your help. Unfortunately your output is different from what I would expect. The dataset that I am considering has Node, Target and Edge/Node's attributes column. I would like to create one file that includes only Nodes and their attributes (column Label_S, Prop_1, and so on). The nodes should be unique and they should come from both Node and Target columns (as I might have some node that is under the Node column but not in Target and vice versa). Then, once I have the list (with no duplicates) I should associate each node with its  properties

Comment: I do not need lists or separate Source/Target as you did, just one unique list with distinct nodes and for each of them the corresponding properties. At the end, I would expect only four columns, like in the example provided in my original question. Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: OK I think I better understand now. Check my updated answer. What do you wanna do with Weight though?

Comment: Thanks Tranbi. I have got this error for the Target (when I define df_t): `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 4.` Do you know what it means and, eventually, how I can fix it?

Comment: hard to tell without further details. Maybe missing brackets... have you tried with the code of my answer as is? please update your question with details of the problem (or create a new one depending on how it is related to the initial question)